# What is a chemistry test?

Tags: casting, film-industry

In the context of casting for a movie, what is a chemistry test and how is it performed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It test how two actors can relate to each other. Generally the male and female lead.

Here's a good article about the same [The Chemistry Test](http://myfilmproject09.blogspot.com/2011/08/chemistry-test.html).

> Apparently the producers and studios want to be absolutely sure that the lead actors have chemistry, otherwise known as attraction,  compatibility, comfort and any other vague quality that might translate to the movie.

Comment: So how exactly does this work? They lock them in a room together and see what happens? They let them act out some scenes? They send them to a candle light dinner and see if they run out of topics to talk about? Neither your answer nor the article you link to answer "how is it performed"?

Comment: #2, mostly. Act out some scenes, see how well they channel their characters as they interact.